# XML Spreadsheet copy to clipboard in vb.net with special character

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, clipboard

I can paste some Excel data (XML Spreadsheet format) to the clipboard with this code :

```
Dim textToPaste as String = GetMyXMLFormattedText()

Dim dataobj As New DataObject 
Dim xmlStream as new IO.MemoryStream()
xmlStream.Write(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToPaste), 0, textToPaste.Length)
dataObj.SetData("XML Spreadsheet", xmlStream)

Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj)
```

where textToPaste is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
...
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

This example works but if i have special characters in my document like "é" i get some "?". 
I tried to use others formats to write my stream like

```
System.Text.UTF32Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes
```

and many others available, or techniques using GetByteCount on the TextToPaste but when i try to paste to excel, i always get an error telling me that i can't paste this data.

Is it possible to paste something else than ASCII to clipboard using XML Spreadsheet Format ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally fill my purpose using System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode to encode each characters in ascii code. Excel is capable of understanding this code. Here's an example (with basic concatenation)

```
<Data ss:Type=""String"">" & System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(MyTextwithéë) & "</Data>
```

in this case, the ASCII copy paste is enough.